# Tikz graphdrawing node distance

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs, tikz-graphdrawing

I would like to create certain graphs in Tikz with a given node distance. I tried:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,positioning,graphdrawing.layered}

\begin{document}

Setting the distance does not work:
\[
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=10pt]
        \graph[nodes={draw,circle,minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0pt,as=}]
        { 1--[draw=gray]2--[draw=gray]3; 1--[bend left]3; };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]

Setting the distance works:
\[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \graph[layered layout,grow=right,level distance=10pt,nodes={draw,circle,minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0pt,as=}]
        { 1--[draw=gray]2--[draw=gray]3;  };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]

Adding third edge changes layout:
\[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \graph[layered layout,grow=right,level distance=10pt,nodes={draw,circle,minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0pt,as=}]
        { 1--[draw=gray]2--[draw=gray]3;  1--[bend left]3; };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image: graph output]

Basically I want the first graph but with the node distance of the second graph. So my question is, how can I set the node distance in `\graph` without specifying a layout (like the layered layout)?

Comment: is it ok now -- if not please give a hand sketch of the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,positioning,}

\begin{document}

Setting the distance does not work:
\[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \graph[nodes={draw,circle,minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0pt,as=}]
        { 1--[draw=gray]2--[draw=gray]3; 1--[bend left]3; };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]

Setting the distance works:
\[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \graph[nodes={draw,circle,minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0pt,as=}]
        { 1--[draw=gray]2--[draw=gray]3;  };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]

Adding third edge changes layout:
\[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \graph[nodes={draw,circle,minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0pt,as=}]
        { 1--[draw=gray]2--[draw=gray]3;  1--[bend left]3; };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```